# How to find difference between two text files in different directories in ubuntu os through command-line

Tags: linux

I am trying to find the difference between two files which are at different paths.
For example, `abc.txt` is at home folder and the `abc2.txt` is at desktop in ubuntu os

How can I find the difference between these two files "`abc.txt` and `abc2.txt`" through command line?

This is the command I tried in my system

```
diff abc.txt /home/abc/desktop/abc2.txt
```

Comment: You used `diff` so what is the problem here? Did it not work? If so what errors did you encounter?

Comment: install meld diff viewer.the command you have written is correct just see file path and name are correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
diff abc.txt /home/abc/desktop/abc2.txt
```

Make sure that terminal place shows same place with `abc.txt`. [pwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/pwd.1posix.html) helps you to see current location.