# How can i find the difference between two files in cmd

Tags: windows, file, text, cmd, compare

I am trying to compare two files and get the output in another text file. So far I have checked and found only solutions to Unix or other OS, but I am looking for a Windows 10 solution.

These are what I have looked at so far:

[Find the difference between two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251188/find-the-difference-between-two-files)

[How to find difference between two text files in different directories in ubuntu os through command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915462/how-to-find-difference-between-two-text-files-in-different-directories-in-ubuntu)

https://www.howtogeek.com/206123/how-to-use-fc-file-compare-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/compare-two-files-unix/

https://superuser.com/questions/805522/compare-two-files-and-output-the-differences

This sort of work but not exactly:

```
fc D:\Logs\Allchannels.txt D:\Logs\check.txt > D:\Logs\missing.txt
```

The output this gives is a list of whats in both files, then the user will have to manually have to look at the files and find out the difference themselves.

What I want is a text file that only shows what's missing between the two.

Example of whats in the two fils:

> file 1:
>
> > - Cart
> > - Box
> > - Money
>
> file 2:
>
> > - Cart
> > - Money

so the output on the 3rd file should be `Box` as this is the value that's missing.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21601688/10515117)

Comment: One this I noticed is that I have a name called ColorsHD and it's saying its missing from the list but it's not missing

Comment: fixed, it just doesnt like the first line

Answer (score 0):

You could use Git BASH https://gitforwindows.org/
and do similar to what you had, with this command:

```sh
git diff path/to/file-1 path/to/file-2 > diff.txt
```

Comment: Hi, This again gives all the other information
Although it has a - in front of the missing item
it has other information, is there a way to clear it up

Comment: @@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 food
-cart
 money
\ No newline at end of file

Answer (score 0):

You can also minimize some of the git diff output using:

```
git diff -U0 --output-indicator-new "" --output-indicator-old "" file1.txt file2.txt
```